# iOS6+ Custom component creation guide

Tags: ios7, ios6, uiviewcontroller, components, ios7.1

I'm starting the iOS development and need to find out what is required to create custom component. I have a few of them to build like star rating bar (which promising tutorial I've found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view) btw.) or download button with progress like it is in the App Store app.

Instead of searching for ready built solutions I would like to learn on how to build it thus my question, is there any **up-to-date** guides on how to accomplish it? Using OOP rules:) ofcourse as I'm used to it from ActionScript and JAVA.